# C++11 Reformatting time output

Tags: delphi, c++11, time

I'm relatively new to C++ and struggling with this.

I have a function of a library which returns a time. The documentation of the function is this (this is all that I have, the library is compiled and given a header file only):

C++

```
TDateTime iTime( PChar Symbol, int TimeFrame, int index );
```

Get the "Time" value of the candle where "Symbol" – a currency name, "TimeFrame" – the selected timeframe, "index" – a bar index from 0 (the last bar has index = 0, the last but one = 1 and so on).

Parameters:

Symbol

A currency name.

TimeFrame

Timeframe in minutes.

index

Bar index.

Example:

```
double time = iTime("USDJPY", 15, 10);
```

In the header file TDateTime is defined as double like so:

```
#define TDateTime double
```

I've just found out that the date format TDateTime (or in reality a double) is a  Borland Delphi datetime format.

How to I convert from Delphi into a cpp human readable format in order to print it out to the console e.g. DD/MM/YY HH:mm:SS

Could someone please show me how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not the right site to ask people to "bare with you". You probably want one of those paid services that charge by the minute.

Comment: No-one can say without knowing how this function from the unspecified library represents a time in a `double`. Since you have the library, you probably also have the documentation.

Comment: @Mike Kinghan
Here's the complete doc that is relevant to c++

C++

 
`
TDateTime iTime(

PChar Symbol,

int TimeFrame,

int index

);
`

 

Get the "Time" value of the candle where "Symbol" – a currency name, "TimeFrame" – the selected timeframe, "index" – a bar index from 0 (the last bar has index = 0, the last but one = 1 and so on).

 

Parameters:

Symbol

A currency name.

TimeFrame

Timeframe in minutes.

index

Bar index.

 
C++

 
double time = iTime("USDJPY", 15, 10);

Comment: Post any information relevant to your question in the question itself,
not in comments. Since the function returns a `TDateTime` (although
you represent it returning `double`), you need to
post the specification of `TDateTime`,  
at least the library documentation of it and preferably also the C++ class or type definition.